# Custom Navbar in Gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am having an issue with a custom navbar. I ain't going to lie, I did copy it but I wanted to make it better. The issue specifically I am having is on the mobile side. When I click a link in the navbar, the navbar menu doesn't disappear. It stays out and the page loads to the clicked link. How can I use useEffect or State or props to make the navbar slide out of the view?

By the way, tailwindCss and bootstrap are out of the question for me because I wanted to use styled components and get my css skills up too.

I appreciate any feedback.

edited code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

const Navigation = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  background-color: var(--white);
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--light-green-shadow);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  z-index: 2;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background ease-out 300ms;
  background: ${({ background }) => background ? `var(--light-green-tint)` : `var(--light-green)`};

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    height: 5vh;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
`

const Toggle = styled.div`
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10vw;

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    display: flex;
  }
`

const Navbox = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  ul {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100;
        justify-content: end;
        gap: 2rem;
        padding: 0 1rem;
        flex-direction: row;
        li {
            list-style: none;
            transition: transform 500ms;
            :hover {
                transform: translateY(-10px);

            }
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                transition: color 300ms, transform 500ms;
                color: var(--white);
                :hover {
                    color: var(--light-grey);
                } 
            }
        }
    }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding-top: 10vh;
    background-color: var(--black);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    top: 6.5vh;
    right: ${({open}) => open ? "0" : "-100%"};
    ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
`

const LogoStyle = styled.div`
    margin-left: 2.5rem;
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        white-space: nowrap; 
        font-size: 1.65rem;
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    }
`;

const Hamburger = styled.div`
  background-color: #111;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  align-self: center;
  position: relative;
  transform: ${({open}) => open ? "rotate(-45deg)" : "inherit"};

  ::before,
  ::after {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #111;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
  }

  ::before {
    transform: ${({open}) => open ? "rotate(-90deg) translate(-10px, 0px)" : "rotate(0deg)"};
    top: -10px;
  }

  ::after {
    opacity: ${({open}) => open ? "0" : "1"};
    transform: ${({open}) => open ? "rotate(90deg) " : "rotate(0deg)"};
    top: 10px;
  }
`
const Navbar = () => {
  const [navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = useState(false);

  const [background, setBackground] = useState(false);
    

  const changeBackground = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 25) {
          setBackground(true);
      } else {
          setBackground(false);
      }
  }

  const toggleNavbar = () => setNavbarOpen(open => !open);

  useEffect(() => {


      window.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);
      console.log(background);
      return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeBackground)
      }
  },[background]);


  return (
    <Navigation background={background}>
       <LogoStyle> 
          <Link to="/">Performant Web Design</Link>
        </LogoStyle>
      <Toggle
        onClick={ toggleNavbar()}
      >
      <Hamburger open={navbarOpen} />
      </Toggle>
      <Navbox open={navbarOpen}>
        <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to='/services'>Services</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </Navbox>
    </Navigation>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when navigating to another page the state should be reset. The `onClick` in the `Link` won't get any effect because it's not a prop accepted by the component (it's not your components, it's Gatsby's). Try debugging there because all the solutions dirty the code, because it should be the default behavior.

What you can do in the meantime, is to intercept that click in your `<li>`

```
const handleClick=(to)=>{
   setNavbarOpen(false);
   navigate(to);
}

<li onClick={handleClick('/services')}>
    <span>Services</span>
</li>
```

*Note: this should be a **temporary solution** while you find the cause of the unsettled state*

---

Taking your words of making it better, you can refactor this:

```
  const closeNav = () => {
    if (navbarOpen) {
      setNavbarOpen(false)
    }
  }

  const openNav = () => {
    if (!navbarOpen) {
      setNavbarOpen(true)
    }
  }
```

Into this:

```
  const toggleNavbar = () => setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen)
```

And this:

```
{navbarOpen ? <Hamburger open /> : <Hamburger />}
```

Into this:

```
<Hamburger open={navbarOpen} />
```

And this:

```
      {navbarOpen ? (
        <Navbox>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/services" >Services</Link>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <IconComponent />
        </Navbox>
      ) : (
        <Navbox open>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/services" onClick={closeNav}>Services</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </Navbox>
      )}
```

Into just this:

```
        <Navbox open={navbarOpen}>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/services" onClick={closeNav}>Services</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </Navbox>
      )}
```

I will help you to debug much better (among other things).

Comment: Appreciate your help, yea the refractor definitly worked and I cleaned up the styling a little. But yea running into the same issues as before with the code link. It works with a plain <a> tag. The navigate method does change the page and the expierence of that quick load is there too, however, still having issues with the menu bar. It's a little weird because when the navbarOpen state is false, the  component should change. I don't know what to do and I been stuck on this for a good time. Would it help if I showed you the styled components too?

Comment: Absolutely. Try sharing a codesandbox if you can, it will be faster to help there than guessing or viewing parts of the code

Comment: It it possible I can send you a link to my github? code sandbox isn't working. Not sure if it's because I have cross-env as a dependency to use ES6 Modules over commonJS

Comment: Try to share as much info as you can but keep in mind this is not an on-demand platform and cloning the project is slower than customizing it live in a sandbox. It works with the regular `<a>` because it refreshes the page (outside the scope of React) so you render everything again, so the state is reset. With Gatsby's router you only refresh the needed parts (the parts which state is different), that's why I suggested the CodeSandbox, to check how's everything set up. Have you tried the "dirty approach"? (just to check that it works or not)

Comment: The solution behaved the same way actually and thanks for showing me that way because I was reading the docs a bit more on the navigate function.

Now I am having an issue because react is saying that my Navbar component is rerendering in an infinity loop. I used a useRef(true) on a variable to see if it will escape from the loop but not sure why it's causing that now.

 lol I created a whole new problem

The OP comment will have the code  from the navbar component

Comment: Use a `useRef(null)` (initially)

Comment: yea I actually changed the Toggle's onclick from {() =>toggleNavbar() } to just {toggleNavbar} and it worked, I suppose that made it so it kept on running the togglenavbar function constantly

Comment: lol I don't know why it wasn't working when I tried it before but I added an onClick to the Link component and it worked...finally!! Thank you and happy coding my friend.